# In the movie Big, is Josh getting older?

Tags: big

My kids watched this the other night and were wondering if Josh was actually getting older after he turned "Big".   Is he going to stay the same age forever, get older from the point of turning "Big", or stay the same age until "real Josh" becomes that age, then get older (if he remains Big and does not return to be a boy)?

Comment: Why would he stay the same age forever? That was not the premise of the movie.

Answer (score 0):

The ending of the movie should actually explain this; Josh returns to his original age.  The movie is in the [Fantasy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fantasy_film) genre, and so requires [Suspension of Disbelief](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suspension_of_disbelief).  The events of the film aren't really possible, and so Josh's turning into an adult and then turning back into a child are just to be assumed as possible, even though we all know it's not.

At the end of the movie, Josh finds the fortune telling machine that granted his wish to be an adult, and makes another wish to return to his younger self.  The events of the movie take place over a very brief time, I think maybe a couple weeks, so at the end of the movie Josh is assumed to be that much older than he was at the start of the movie, but that's mostly inconsequential.  The point is, he returns to the age of 12, which was his age at the beginning of the movie.  Everything in-between was merely magic.  Adult Josh disappears, just as Child Josh disappeared when he turned big.

Comment: That wasn't the question.   The question is if he stayed Big what would his age be?   The ending didn't explain this at all.

Comment: In Lord of The Rings, why didn't they just ride the Eagles to Mordor?  Because that's not how the story went.  Same thing.  It's irrelevant and unanswerable.  The only answer is; that's not how it was written.

Comment: I didn't remember anything from the movie but thought it could be from an extra scene, alternative ending, book or whatever.   Maybe it is unanswerable but figured I would get an answer from someone that might know better.

Comment: The also asked me if the lady was going to jail for sleeping with a 13 year old - but that's for another site!

Comment: In that case, I voted to close the question because it's opinion based and not allowable in the community.

Comment: The question isn't answerable.  It's based on a premise that doesn't exist in the movie, and is therefore opinion.  Perhaps you should read the Beta on what questions are allowed?  To quote you: "The question is if he stayed Big what would his age be?"  This is a hypothetical ending, and can only generate opinion-based answers.

Comment: The way you asked the question, I provided an answer.  It wasn't until later that you changed the gist of the question and it became unanswerable.  I'm quite aware of Beta, have you ever visited that site?  You don't get to 52K rep providing poor answers, maybe you should re-read your question?

Comment: Apparently a few other people had trouble reading it, too.  *shrugs*